# A $W^{1,p}$ function that is unbounded on any open subset of $B_1(0)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm currently studying the properties of Sobolev Spaces in calculus of variations and functional analysis and was wondering if there is a function, that is $W^{1,p}$ but is unbounded on any open subset of $B_1(0)$.

Comment: Do you know an example of a function $f$ in $W^{1,p}$ that is unbounded in every neighborhood of a single point?

Comment: How about $u(x)$ piecewise with $u(x) = \frac{1}{\vert x \vert ^\alpha}$ outside of $0$ and $u(0) = 0$. For certain $\alpha(n,p)$ we have $u \in W^{1,p}$ and its unbounded on any neighbourhood around $0$.

Comment: Right. If you enumerate the rationals in $B_1(0)$ by $\{q_k\}$ and define $u_k(x) = 2^{-k} u(x-q_k)$, then $\sum \|u_k\|_{1,p}$ converges (as a real number), so that $\sum u_k$ converges in $W^{1,p}$. This function is unbounded at every rational point. This is the idea behind the answer given below.

Comment: Thanks for the help, though I'm still trying to understand the function. What do you mean by "$\sum \Vert u_k \Vert_{1,p}$ converges as a real number"? $u_k$ is in $W_{1,p}$ so every summand is a real number. How does $\sum u_k$ then converge to something in $W^{1,p}$? Is it the $2^k$ in the denominater which gives us convergence?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard example is given in section 5.2.2 of Evans' book (p.260 in the second edition), and is
$$u(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|x - r_k|^{-\alpha}}{2^k}$$
where $\{r_k\}_k$ is a countable, dense subset of your set $U$. This function is in $W^{1, p}(U)$ if $\alpha < (n - p) / p$.